# Android Error when closing the application

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have an android programm which manage a database. It this database, I write the sensor values of my device.

When close the application with the home button, i have a force close error.

Here is my logcat, can you please help me, thank you.

```
`12-27 10:45:20.827: D/AndroidRuntime(1053): Shutting down VM  
12-27 10:45:20.827: W/dalvikvm(1053): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): java.lang.NullPointerException  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:283)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:116)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1732)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at milos.stationdemesure.CapteursBDD.insertValeursCapteur(CapteursBDD.java:69)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at milos.stationdemesure.EssaisCapteurs.onProximityChanged(EssaisCapteurs.java:454)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at milos.stationdemesure.EssaisCapteurs.onSensorChanged(EssaisCapteurs.java:354)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:529)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)  
12-27 10:45:20.942: E/AndroidRuntime(1053):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
`
```

Comment: Lack of code code doesn't help. I guess that unregistering sensor listener could fix this issue.

Comment: You insert null value or some thing is null in your code

Comment: if you past the full logcat it should give you a hint to where in your code you are getting the Bull exception pointer.  I would guess something in one of the onStop or onDestroy functions of one of your activities.

Comment: Uh, my code is tooo big, i have listeners but normaly, i am unregistering all of them at the end.

I think I have found the problem, i am closing my DataBase on closing application with nameOfThBase.close();
Which is normal i think. When i have deleted this instruction, all works well.

Do yo know why???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999075/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the issue is either database instance or any other object became null but you are calling some method using that object. **Always check for null before using any methods of any object**. see the sample example

example

```
if(database != null){
database.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Sunil Kumar Sahoo, ah ok, i see.
But database !=0 what is means? TWhen database=0, the base is already closed???


Thank you

Comment: database!= null means you are check whther the database is nullified if yes then you can call any methods of database

Comment: No, look at the stack trace. NPE is coming from _within_ SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to this issue: [SQLiteDatabase close() function causing NullPointerException when multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999075/sqlitedatabase-close-function-causing-nullpointerexception-when-multiple-threa)

You may not need to call database.close()