# Android: How to close a cursor that returns from Class to Activity

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have: Accounts.java

```
public class Accounts{

    private SQLiteDatabase dbConfig;

public Cursor list(Context context, String db, String where, String order) {

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context, db);
    dbConfig = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = dbConfig.query("accounts", new String[]{ "iId","sName"}, where, null, null, null, order);
    return c;   
    }
}
```

and: MainActivity.java

```
Accounts account = new Accounts();
Cursor cursor =  account.list(getApplicationContext(), globalDB, null, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
     int id = cursor.getInt(0);
     String name = cursor.getString(1);
}
cursor.close();
```

Running my application I get some logcat messages like:

```
close() was never explicitly called on database...
```

What is the best way to prevent it? How can I close a Cursor that returns from other class?
Thanks

Comment: you need to close the db.if not done then make sure you close it when activity is destroyed

Comment: @Vipul No, you don't need to close the db. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7999153/385478

Answer (score 1):

After `account.list()` exits, the underlying database connection is still open, but there are no remaining references to it. So, it has leaked.

You can close the database once you're finished with it, or you can keep it open for the lifetime of your application by having a single global database connection which you open once, share amongst all your activities, and never close.

I recommend the latter approach. It results in much simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling `cursor.close();` you can call and create a `Accounts.close()` method that closes both cursor and database