# How to handle 2 connections to database without error?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locked

I have a problem with my database.

Basically my applications read texts and rates of text from my SQLite database and show it on screen. I have also Thread function which downloads content from external internet server and uploads it into the database.

On less popular devices (mostly tablets) it generates errors like:

```
DB close exception
DB locked
```

Someone advised me to create something called a singleton to handle this and I created it but it generates errors. So I have an idea to use AsyncTask instead of Thread; do you think it will help? 
Maybe you have other solutions?

Comment: I don't see why using AsyncTask would change anything for your issue

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` will not help you here. You have to create a database connection as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a readable database for when you are reading and a writable database for when you are writing. Then you will be able to do both at the same time.

Both of the methods are in the [SQLHelper class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Never close the DB. Make sure you have only one Helper instance per application.
See this for reference [SQLiteDatabase close() function causing NullPointerException when multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999075/sqlitedatabase-close-function-causing-nullpointerexception-when-multiple-threa)

This may help you :)