# Android SQLite update gets rolled back on app relaunch

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to perform an update on a table which contains only 1 row. The update gets performed successfully but as soon as I relaunch the app, the update gets rolled back!
Here is my code:

```
public void updateToken(String token) {
    System.out.println("DatabaseHandler.updateToken");
    System.out.println("Value of token: " + token);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from ui", null);
    String data = "";
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        for(int i= 0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            data += cursor.getString(i) + " | ";
        }
        data += "\n";
    }
    Log.i("UI Table before update",data);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("gcmtoken", token);
    db.beginTransaction();
    int r = db.update("ui", values, "ui = ?", new String[]{"" + getUI()});
    System.out.println("Number of rows affected: " + r);
    System.out.println("Updated GCMToken in DB: " + getGCMToken());
    cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from ui", null);
    data = "";
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        for(int i= 0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            data += cursor.getString(i) + " | ";
        }
        data += "\n";
    }
    Log.i("UI Table after update",data);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

The corresponding output shows the previous token in first `Log.i()` and new token in second `Log.i()` on every launch of app.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: `a table which contains only 1 row` Wouldn't SharedPreferences be more efficient?

Comment: @BobMalooga True, I want to move to SharedPreferences once I know what's wrong with my code. I just recently discovered about SharedPreferences :)

Comment: Well, it's even easier than databases... ;)

Comment: @BobMalooga:
Fighting this bug since last 2 hours and seeing those colorful long identifier names in the tutorials, doesn't seem easy to me at all xD

Comment: @BobMalooga quick question, are `SharedPreferences` safe for saving sensitive information?

Comment: Absolutely **NO**. Since it's an xml file. If the user roots their phone, your're cracked.

Comment: @BobMalooga: If the user roots, he can access the database too..

Comment: Yes, but at least you can encrypt it with SQLCipher.

Comment: @BobMalooga: This is why I want to use Database for my problem.

Comment: OK. I thought it was unsensible data.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the connection to the database, and maybe the data is not actually written because of that. If you do not explicitly close the database connection, when you exit your application all connections will be closed, but this won't assure you the data to be stored successfully.

Add a `db.close()` statement after your `db.endTransaction()` line.

Good luck!

Comment: Strangely this never happened when I insert records. I read somewhere on stackoverflow that it is a good practice to leave DB connection open.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal `I read somewhere on stackoverflow that it is a good practice to leave DB connection open.` I think it was an April's fool.

Comment: Maybe if you intend to keep using it for further DB operations. Otherwise It has no sense keeping it open. I close them always and it works fine.

Comment: Well if you use `db.close()` then it will throw can't operate on closed connection exception.. something like that.
@BobMalooga Did you see that I mentioned in the question that the results get rolled back after app restart? while the app is running the results reflect like they should normally. And yet again, I never faced this problem with inserts

Comment: Obviously enough, you have to re/open the db before using it. Then close it as soon as you used it. your mantra: `open the db, use it, close it`.

Comment: @BobMalooga: Could you please add a short pseudo that should be followed each function of my helper class to your answer?

Comment: I never answered this question... ;)

Comment: Have you solved it yet? I think there could be a problem on naming your attribute `ui` identical as your table `ui`. So maybe your condition `ui = ?` is not doing what you think it should do. Try renaming the table or the attribute and tell us if it worked.

Comment: @BobMalooga : Refer this answer about our discussion about leaving DB open or not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7999153/5157706

Juan: that can't be the issue because it worked before the app relaunches.

Sorry for getting back this late guys!

Comment: @AkashAggarwal My best option is following the mantra: `Open it, use it, close it`.