# Android 'simple' database scenario: Is it better to close using database.close() or databaseHelper.close()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In an Android 'simple' database scenario, is there any benefit or reason to use *database.close()* and Not *databaseHelper.close()* ?  Is there any benefit or reason to use *databaseHelper.close()* and Not *database.close()* ?

Is there a technical reason why both these close methods (shown below) exist?

Thanks,
James

```
MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues valuesToInsert = new ContentValues();
   int id = 0;
   valuesToInsert.put("_id", id);
   valuesToInsert.put("name", "test");
   database.insert("MyRecordsTable", null, valuesToInsert);
database.close();
```

OR

```
MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues valuesToInsert = new ContentValues();
   int id = 0;
   valuesToInsert.put("_id", id);
   valuesToInsert.put("name", "test");
   database.insert("MyRecordsTable", null, valuesToInsert);
databaseHelper.close();
```

Comment: Good read http://stackoverflow.com/a/8532043/786337

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a huge difference. This is the whole definition of `close()` within `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
/**
 * Close any open database object.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mIsInitializing) throw new IllegalStateException("Closed during initialization");

    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        mDatabase.close();
        mDatabase = null;
    }
}
```

The reason both exist, is that there may be instances where developers only use `SQLiteOpenHelper` for interfacing with their database and want the `close()` method as a convenience to directly access the DB, or vice versa if developers don't choose to use the OpenHelper at all.